# Count the ups and downs

Tags: prolog

In SWI-Prolog, I want to count how many times the user types `up` and `down`. Every time he types `up`, the up counter (xu) will be increased and the down counter (xd) will be decreased. The same will happen when the user types down.This what I have:

```
:- dynamic xd/1, xu/1.

xd(0).
xu(0).

up :- 
   retract(xu(Xu)),
   succ(Xu, Xu1),
   asserta(xu(Xu1)), 
   retract(xd(Xd)),
   succ(Xd1,Xd),
   asserta(xd(Xd1)).

down :- 
   retract(xd(Xd)),
   succ(Xd, Xd1),
   asserta(xd(Xd1)),
   retract(xu(Xu)),
   succ(Xu1,Xu),
   asserta(xu(Xu1)).
```

But I have 2 problems:

Whenever the user types `up.` or `down.`, he gets `false.` but the xu or xd (respectively) *is* being increased. For instance

```
   1 ?- down.
   false.

   2 ?- down.
   false.

   3 ?- xd(X).
   X = 2.
```

The second problem I have is that if the user starts typing `up.` a couple of times, and then `down.`, the xd counter won't increase. For instance:

```
1 ?- down.
false.

2 ?- down.
false.

3 ?- xd(X).
X = 2.

4 ?- up.
false.

5 ?- xu(X).
false.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with [`succ/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=succ/2). *It only works on positive numbers.*

From the documentation

> `succ(X, 0)` fails silently

Assertions and retractions, however, are not backtrackable. So the increased counter gets asserted, while the decreased value only gets retracted, but never asserted. That's why you're seeing

```
5 ?- xu(X).
false.
```

instead of

```
5 ?- xu(X).
X = 0.
```

---

I recommend you use `X1 is X + 1` and `X1 is X - 1` instead.

Comment: Is there something similar that will work with both negative and positive numbers?

Comment: The first up is true but the i get `ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

Comment: This is my up: `up:- retract(xu(Xu)), X1 is Xu+1, asserta(xu(Xu1)), 
     retract(xd(Xd)), Xd1 is Xd-1, asserta(xd(Xd1)).`